# Can occur more than a global min in a closed interval of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The question is simple but it's the first time I've dealt with it. If I consider some cubic functions on a closed interval, may happen to have more than a global minima. For example, considering  $f(x)=x^3-3x^2$ at $[-1,4]$ I see that I get $(-1,-4)$ at the left boundary of the closed interval and I get $(2,-4)$ as location of a stationary point. Thus, they have the same height and they are both global minima on the closed interval, right?

Comment: The minimum (as I understand it) is the minimal function *value*, in your case $-4$. That value can be attained for many different values of $x$. Think of a constant function as an extremal case.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get. Are you saying that I am right?

Comment: There can be *many* differetn $x$-values where the same *unique* minimal $y$-value is attained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the minimum value that $f$ attains, can be attained at multiple $x$-values.

For example consider $g(x)=\sin(x)$, which has global minimum $-1$, which is attained at an infinite number of points.

Or even simpler, a constant function like $h(x)=5$ has global minimum $5$, which is attained *for every* $x$.